# C++ Writing a DWORD value to all subkeys of a certain registry key

Tags: c++, registry, key, dword

I have trouble making this code I found work for me.

**Now**: It adds 2 DWORD values the the Interface folder (registry key) in registry.

**Desired**: I would want it to add those 2 DWORD values to ALL the subkeys (subfolders) of the Interface registry key (folder).

I have got this pseudo code:

- Open the parent key with RegOpenKey or RegOpenKeyEx
- Enumerate all of the child keys of the parent using RegEnumKey or RegEnumKeyEx in a loop
- For each child key, set the desired value with RegSetValueEx
- Close the parent key with RegCloseKey

I'll keep trying to get this sorted, but maybe someone can help?

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

HKEY OpenKey(HKEY hRootKey, wchar_t* strKey)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG nError = RegOpenKeyEx(hRootKey, strKey, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
    if(nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "Creating registry key: " << strKey << endl;
        nError = RegCreateKeyEx(hRootKey, strKey, NULL, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL, &hKey, NULL);
    }
    if(nError)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not find or create " << strKey << endl;
    }
    return hKey;
}

void SetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue, DWORD data)
{
    LONG nError = RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(DWORD));
    if(nError)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not set registry value: " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
    }
}

DWORD GetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue)
{
    DWORD data;
    DWORD size = sizeof(data);
    DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
    LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);
    if(nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        data = 0;    // The value will be created and set to data next time SetVal() is called.
    }
    else if(nError)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not get registry value " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
    }
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    static DWORD v1, v2;
    HKEY hKey = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\");
    v1 = GetVal(hKey, L"Registry Value1");
    v2 = GetVal(hKey, L"Registry Value2");
    v1 += 5;
    v2 += 2;
    SetVal(hKey, L"Registry Value1", v1);
    SetVal(hKey, L"Registry Value2", v2);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for concise code snippet. If I'm getting this right you just want to find the code to enumerate subkeys (not shown)?

Comment: Indeed. I mean, Ive tried many things so that I could add the DWORD values to all subkeys of the Interface registry key. I cant get any further than adding the DWORD values to the Interface key. Enumerating the subkeys and adding the DWORD value to all of them seems to be impossible for me. By the way, thanks for editing and making my text clearer :)

Comment: If you need code to enumerate through the subkeys, there's actual sample code to do that. Look at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256(v=vs.85).aspx
That will show you how to enumerate through all subkeys.
Good luck!

Comment: You will need to: a) enumerate subkeys, b) open each subkey, c) write out desired DWORD values to that opened subkey, d) close subkey.

Comment: StarPilot, Ive read that page through multiple times yesterday and today, Ive tried implementing that exact code into my code but I just fail every single time, theres something I simply cannot understand. I think its something far too hardcore for my small knowledge. Ill try pushing, though. Would you happen to know how to exactly do it, as in the code itself? I believe Ive been doing it in some VERY VERY wrong way that probably to an advanced programmer would look ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare minimum example without any extras:

```
// open desired key whose subkeys shall be enumerated
HKEY hKey={0};
LPCTSTR path=TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces");
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,path,0,KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS,&hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return; // failed to open
DWORD index=0;           // enumeration index
TCHAR keyName[256]={0};  // buffer to store enumerated subkey name
DWORD keyLen=256;        // buffer length / number of TCHARs copied to keyName
// enumerate subkey names of hKey, result stored in keyName, keyLen set to strlen(keyName)
while(RegEnumKeyEx(hKey,index++,keyName,&keyLen,0,0,0,0) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    keyLen=256; // reset buffer length (RegEnumKeyEx changes this value)
    // open the subkey and set the desired value(s)
    HKEY hSubKey={0};
    if(RegOpenKeyEx(hKey,keyName,0,KEY_SET_VALUE,&hSubKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // set desired value(s):
        DWORD myValue = 0xCAFEBABE;
        //RegSetValueEx(hSubKey,TEXT("MyValueName"),0,REG_DWORD,(LPBYTE)&myValue,sizeof(DWORD));
        RegCloseKey(hSubKey); // close sub key
    } 
    // else: failed to open subkey
}
// RegEnumKeyEx either returns ERROR_SUCCESS, ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS, or a system error code
RegCloseKey(hKey); // close key
```

Please note, this example does not evaluate error codes. It simply demonstrates the process of enumerating sub keys and setting a value. The RegOpenKeyEx access rights are set to the minimum required to perform this task (set them to whatever you wish to do with the opened keys). The while loop does not distinct from ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS (once there are no more subkeys to enumerate) or an actual error. RegSetValueEx is commented out for safety and its return value is ignored.